# Redirect to subdirectory path for the page links having absolute path

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

For an instance, primary URL is http://example.com running on apache server.

I want to put my project in subdirectories as root>projects>thekingfisher resulting into

http://example.com/projects/thekingfisher/

With htaccess, I could access the project

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /projects/thekingfisher/
</Ifmodule>
```

But, some of the files have absolute paths, which are not accessible as in below file

/root/projects/thekingfisher/index.php

```
<html>
  <head>
  <link href="/css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Test Page</h1>
    <a href="/about.php">About</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

As I run my project http://example.com/projects/thekingfisher/

**Expected Behaviour:**

1. I want to load the file "css/styles.css" from root/projects/thekingfisher/
2. Also, "About" link should navigate to "http://example.com/projects/thekingfisher/about.php"

**Actual Scenario:**

1. style.css file is being searched at root/css/ to be loaded.
2. "About" link navigates to "http://example.com/about.php"

Actually, project runs smooth on root. But not properly loading in the subdirectory.
There are many hyperlinks in such pattern, and gets 404 error when tried.
Since this is active project, I don't want to make edits in the source files for modifying the path like prepending baseurl, etc.

Comment: have you tried putting the full link in the `href` section? or maybe changing it to `"./" + rest_of_link`?

Comment: Yes, then it works. Even if I remove the first slash, it works. I don't want to make changes for each files in project. Rather, I want solution with httaccess or other solution which requires few edits affecting whole project.

Comment: The "./" should tell it you want to search for the file starting from the current directory instead of starting from root

Answer (score 0):

You just need a rule in site root to rewrite all requests to `/projects/thekingfisher/`:

```sh
RewriteEngine On

# if file exists in /projects/thekingfisher/ then rewrite
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/projects/thekingfisher/$0 -f
RewriteBase .* projects/thekingfisher/$0 [L]
```

Comment: There are many other things running at root. So without disturbing them, I preferably want solution with  .htaccess in /projects/thekingfisher/

Comment: `/projects/thekingfisher/.htaccess` cannot control a URI for `example.com/about.php` but I will modify site root .htaccess to handle it only for existing files in `/projects/thekingfisher/`

Comment: This makes sense, I will definitely check it first.

Comment: Doesn't work as expected, I get 500 Internal Server error

Comment: That doesn't tell much. Are you still getting 404 for `http://example.com/about.php` ? Can you check with just this rule for testing purpose?